# How to fetch data from xml?

Tags: sql, plsql

How can I fetch the data out of the query? I need the tags "Result", "ApprovalCode" and "id" from the body:

```
<ns28:response xmlns:ns2="xx" xmlns:ns40="yy" Result="Approved"ApprovalCode="529827"><ns28:Specific><ns14:CardVsdc Id="3"/></ns28:Specific>
```

```
    select Id
      into v_RiskLevel
      from xmltable('/response' passing g_xmlResult columns 
                    Id varchar2(50) path '@ApprovalCode');
```

Comment: @SaintLike Not quite a duplicate of that link as it's Oracle PL/SQL. But it is a duplicate of [Extracting values from xml in Oracle PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923211/extracting-values-from-xml-in-oracle-pl-sql)

Comment: Also it's incomplete XML and not valid in its current state.